# SpaCy: enable previous disabled pipes

Tags: python, spacy

I have a model that contains two pipes: `['sbd', 'tagger']`. The first one is a sentence tokenizer and the second the tagger. Now I want to train a **NER** with this model so that I can have a final model with three pipes: `['sbd', 'tagger','ner']`. According to [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner) I need to disable **`tagger`** pipe in order to train **NER** only. I did it and the training process runned smoothly.

My problem is that in the end, the saved model contains only one pipe, namely the **NER** system. Can I enable back the previous disabled pipes, so that I can save a final model with the full pipeline?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found that I can restore the previously disabled pipes. Assuming I loaded my model in `nlp` and disabled all pipes except `ner`:

```
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
disabled = nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes)

training...

disabled.restore()
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem altogether, you can disable the pipes in a `with` block that is limited to the training scope:

```
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    train_model()

# continue with other stuff
```